# exhibition v.s. inhibition

Tags: word-usage, differences, synonyms, antonyms, contemporary-english

In my experience...

- [Inhibition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inhibition) is commonly used in different ways, say to render
  difficult, or to hide, to restrict or hinder, etc.
- [Exhibition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exhibition) can be something like making and art show, presentations, to display or demonstrate, etc.

However, can these be used as antonyms? When looking the construction of the words say the prefixes of "in" v.s. "ex" (generally in and out), I wonder if these words have evolved in a way where the direct use of the deconstructed can be used in the same literal sense as one would have it today, say the 21st century?

Particularly, if I use these words in the following sentence, would it be incorrect or somewhat ambiguous?

> Alcohol can cause reduced inhibition (behavioral). Alcohol allows the exhibition of one's true unfiltered personality.

Comment: add citations for both words if you please

Comment: @Ibf added oxford links... ?

Comment: a researched question -good

Comment: I can imagine someone pretending they were antonyms, in a (hopefully) humorous article, and one might "play" on their similar sounds (as you did above) as a sort of alliteration, but to actually assume them to be antonyms in any general sense would be a significant mistake.

Comment: @HotLicks I was thinking it would erroneous... Could you provide a usage example where this would be clearly incorrect? That would help greatly. Thanks.

Comment: The antonym for inhibition is "disinhibition".  In the context of your example, consider also "extroversion".

Comment: @Graffito Wow thanks! I think this answers my question!

Comment: From an etymological point of view, inhibition comes from the latin "inhebere" (restrain) and exhibition from "exhibitio" (display) . These two Latin words were not related with the same idea.

Comment: Inhibition is listed as an antonym here: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/exhibition/antonyms/2 Which is what I would expect. According to etymonline, both are from the exact same root. https://www.etymonline.com/word/exhibit

Comment: Ok, now it's a mystery...

Comment: No, Joe, though they seem antonymous and have similar roots and etymologies and still share certain generalities, *inhibition* and *exhibition* specifically lost almost everything in common long ago.

How often have you ever heard “inhibitionist” - so obscure, my spell-checker first offered to correct it, then tried to over-ride my acceptance?

In real speech, when is “he is *an inhibitionist*” not replaced by “he is *inhibited*”, please? When is “he is an *exhibitionist*” ever replaced by “he is *exhibited*”?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I see thanks for the insight. Why is no one posting an answer?

Comment: Ah! Because Answers require detailed research, which would take significant time. What I posted took me seconds; perhaps minutes. An Answer would have taken at very least ten times as long…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I see... I appreciate the help :)